# AJAX post request with django and python

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, post

I am trying to build a web app on django where a user can record something which then gets turned into text and after that sent to the server with AJAX. I did some research and found this article: https://medium.com/@manask322/implementing-speech-to-text-feature-in-a-django-app-f0fa53bb3e03

So I copied the html code: (this is only the part I copied)

```
<div id='result'>
    Your text will  appear here
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id= 'record'>
      <button onclick="startConverting()" class='btn btn-info btn-sm' id="re">record</button>
      <button class='btn btn-info btn-sm ml-3' value="Send" id="send">Send</button>
  </div>

  <script>
     function startConverting()
            {
              document.getElementById("re").style.visibility = "hidden";   
              var r=document.getElementById('result');
              var spr=new webkitSpeechRecognition(); //Initialisation of web Kit
                spr.continuous=false; //True if continous conversion is needed, false to stop transalation when paused 
                spr.interimResults=true;
                spr.lang='en-IN'; // Set Input language
                spr.start(); //Start Recording the voice 
                var ftr='';
                spr.onresult=function(event){
                    var interimTranscripts='';
                    for(var i=event.resultIndex;i<event.results.length;i++)
                    {
                        var transcript=event.results[i][0].transcript;
                        transcript.replace("\n","<br>")
                        if(event.results[i].isFinal){
                            ftr+=transcript;
                        }
                        else
                        interimTranscripts+=transcript;
                    }
                    r.innerHTML=ftr +interimTranscripts ;
                };
                spr.onerror=function(event){};
            }
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#send").click(function(event){
                      $.ajax({
                          type:"POST",
                          url:"/audio_data",
                          data: {
                                  send : $('#result').html()
                                  },
                          
                      });
                });
              });
  </script>
</div>
```

But changed the function in views.py a bit:

```
@csrf_exempt
def audio_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.POST['send']
        return render(request, 'success.html')
        
        
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'afterContinue.html')
```

The recording works and it also displays the text you say but when you click on send nothing happens.
Does someone know why?

UPDATE:
This is the urls.py part:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('audio_data', views.audio_data)
]
```

Comment: why are you looking for send inside request.POST['send']???

Comment: @Syed Khizaruddin I thought that was the name and in the article he does thee same. For what shoul I look instead? for result?

Comment: try printing out request.POST so that you could know whats inside of it

Comment: Should I try to return it as a message?

Comment: `print(request.POST)` output will be seen on terminal where you are running your django development server

Comment: I tried that but nothing happens. I even set a breakpoint at ````if request.method == 'POST':```` but nothing happens

Comment: the data you are sending is not getting at audio_data() function most probably you are sending data which was added by js prior to rendering click function of send hence the that data is not getting binded with click function

Comment: So do what do you suggest? Should I do a form with audio_data as action?

Comment: try it might work because i dont have any more info now about your project

Comment: Now I get a Value error when I click record: ValueError at /audio_data
The view hello.views.audio_data didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

Add the jQuery CDN minified inside the `<head>` tag in html template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="result">
            .......
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Html template**

1. send a parameter `save` to `audio_data` view so that it could recognise that it has to save the audio text.
2. send the ajax request data in json format.
3. Check the response sent by django view was true or not.
4. redirect the user to `/audio_data?success=true` if the response from view was true.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send").click(function(event){
        $.ajax({
            url:  "/audio_data",
            data: {
               'save': true, // Change No.1
               'text': $('#result').html()
            },
            dataType: 'JSON', // Change No.2
            success: function(response) {  // Change No.3
                if (response.ans) {  // Change No.3
                   location.href = '/audio_data?success=true'; // Change No.4
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**views.py**

5. Check if the save parameter is true or not.
6. Check if audio text is provided or not.
7. Return a `JsonResponse` with a dictionary that holds the value of `ans` variable that is `True` if the audio text is saved & is `False` if the text is nor provided.
8. Render the `success.html` template if the `success` parameter is `true`.
9. If both `save` and `success` parameters are `False` or not provided then render `afterContinue.html` template.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

@csrf_exempt
def audio_data(request):
    data = request.GET

    if data.get('save', False): # Change No.5
       ans = True

       text = data.get('text', False) # Change No.6
       if text: // Change No.6
          print('Text = ', text)
          """ Here save the text the way you want. """
       else:
          ans = False

       return JsonResponse({'ans':ans}) # Change No.7

    elif data.get('success', False): # Change No.8
       return render(request, 'success.html')

    return render(request, 'afterContinue.html') # Change No.9
```

Comment: I tried this but I always get to the 'afterContinue.html' after clicking send. Any idea why ? And unfortunatly I am still a beginner so I may haven't understood your answer a 100%

Comment: Okay maybe request data is not reading. Can you print request.GET i.e `print(request.GET)` and share the output in comments?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Okay I'll test it on my local and edit my answer with explaination.

Comment: Okay I found why it was only showing the `afterContinue.html` template. It was because there was a server error that occurred due to `ans=true` because true is not defined.

Comment: Check the updated answer and try it again.

Comment: Stranglely it still returns only the afterContinue.html because the text doesn't get sent by ajax or isn't received. Could the problem maybe the urls.py be or how I positioned the form in the html template?

Comment: No the problem is not that. It is because you have not added the jQuery can in your template. Wait I'll updated the answer.

Comment: It works now. Thank you very much. One thing, how can I now work with the received text in views.py.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227119/discussion-between-ajay-lingayat-and-anonimostilton).